# How can call a PHP function from Perl code?

Tags: php, perl, cgi

I have a function written in PHP and would like to call this inside a CGI script. Is there any direct way to do this?

I am not sure if its even possible. The CGI script will be inside `cgi-bin` directory and the PHP function will be outside this folder.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to ask "How can I invoke PHP code from a CGI?"

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could try to use [Inline::Interp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Inline::Interp) or [PHP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PHP), however, I am not sure I see the point, given the overhead involved in invoking yet another interpreter in a CGI script.

Comment: thanks, can you please provide me an example how to code php inside cgi? so that i can see if it works and confirm if this module is installed.

Comment: @Jay, No, I do not have the time or interest to work out an example beyond what is in the distributions for those modules.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried via Command Line like so:

`open DATA, "/path/to/you/bin/php you_script.php |" or die "Whoops: $!";`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PHP::Interpreter :

```
use PHP::Interpreter;
my $p = PHP::Interpreter->new();
$p->include("some_php_include.php");
my $val = $p->somePhpFunc($perlVal);
```